# BusyIndicator not showing from async method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, busyindicator

I'm trying to upgrade methods, which were previously BackgroundWorker based, to use the async calls from the [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) library.  The trouble I'm having is the busy indicator no longer works with the new async functionality (which I am new to).  The busy indicator does not show, the GUI freezes while the operation executes, and then unfreezes when it is complete.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong...

XAML Code:

```
<Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5,5,15,15" Background="#FFA8A9AC" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
    <Grid x:Name="UIGrid">
        <toolkit:BusyIndicator x:Name="BusyIndicator" IsBusy="{Binding Instance.IsBusy}" BusyContent="{Binding Instance.BusyMessage, TargetNullValue='Please wait...'}" >
            <Grid x:Name="ScreenGrid" />
        </toolkit:BusyIndicator>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Code

```
// Button click handler.
private async void NewReportClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SystemLog.Trace(this);

    await this.CreateReport();
}

// Async implementation.
private async Task CreateReport()
{
    SystemLog.Trace(this);

    await this.CloseReport();

    BusinessLogic.Instance.BusyMessage = "CREATING new report...";
    BusinessLogic.Instance.IsBusy = true;

    await BusinessLogic.Instance.ReportManager.CreateReport();

    BusinessLogic.Instance.IsBusy = false;
    BusinessLogic.Instance.BusyMessage = null;
}
```

Edit:
To reply to @Jon Skeet, here is the important portions of CreateReport:

```
    public async Task CreateReport()
    {
        SystemLog.Trace(this);

        var internalReportId = GenerateReportId();

        var rpt = await ReportFactory.Create();

        rpt.InternalReportId = internalReportId;
        rpt.EnableNotifications = true;

        ReportRepository = new ReportRepository();

        await SaveReport(rpt);

        // Set the active report.
        BusinessLogic.Instance.ActiveReport = rpt;

        await AssignReportNumber(MediViewData.Instance.ActiveReport);
    }

    public async static Task<Report> Create()
    {
        var rpt = new Report();

        /** Set several fields to default values. */

        return rpt;
    }
```

Comment: What does `ReportManager.CreateReport` do? If that just executes synchronously, then it's not going to help you...

Comment: I've added some code to hopefully clarify what it is doing. Does anything stand out as wrong?

Comment: Well which bit actually takes time? Is it `SaveReport`? What does *that* look like? Basically, I suspect you're actually doing most of the work with synchronous calls.

Comment: The largest thing is assigning ActiveReport.  That updates all of the bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not enough information to give you code for an answer, but in general:

First, realize that `async` does not run your code on a background thread. All it does is create a little state machine that enables `await` operations. Likewise, `await` does not run your code on a background thread.

If you have CPU-intensive operations, you should push them off to a background thread using `await Task.Run(..)`. Any kind of data binding is considered a UI operation and should *not* be done inside a call to `Task.Run`.

Comment: I think that has cleared up a lot of my confusion.  The difference between the async and actual background processing.

Comment: You may want to be using `Task.Factory.StartNew`, it provides more options.

Comment: @heap1: `StartNew` also has [dangerous default options](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html). `Task.Run` should be the default choice, with `StartNew` used only if necessary.